# How can I omit information from a customer email receipt that is not selected in the WordPress E&P Form Builder Plugin (using WooCommerce)?

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, mailchimp, receipt

I’m desperate for some answers on an issue I’m having with the E&P form. I am working on a WordPress site that utilizes the E&P form builder, WooCommerce and MailChimp.

We are a bike rack company that allows customers to customize their bike racks based on preferred specifications. We use the E&P form because it allows customers to create their bike racks while also including existing WooCommerce products that will also be billed to the customer. However, there are a couple of issues with the E&P form builder and sending email receipts:

1. when the customer does not select certain items (from a dropdown menu, for example) on a certain section of the form, they still show up in the summary under their section as “select additional product”. Of course, the customer isn’t paying for it, but when they get the email, they see “select additional basket (product)" as a selection. There are also empty sections showing up in their email receipt as well from form sections where they didn’t select anything. It doesn’t necessarily break anything, but it can be confusing for the customer.
2. When a customer does select additional items in the form, but gets rid of them in their WooCommerce cart, the items that were deleted from the WooCommerce cart are still sent to their email receipt along with how much they would have been charged for them (It doesn’t actually charge them since they deleted the items from their cart and weren’t purchased, but it still shows up in their receipt).

My questions is, how can I turn off sending the E&P form summary as an email receipt and send the receipt based on their WooCommerce cart instead? Or even just omit sections if nothing is chosen in those sections?

**Email receipt where empty form fields appear**

[image: Email receipt where empty form fields appear]

**Email receipt where products are being "charged" to the customer**
[image: Email receipt where products are being "charged" to the customer]

I’ve looked for hours in the form settings and online, and I’ve found some options that seem to look like they would work, but end up breaking the rest of the form. The form generally works fine, but it’s just the contents of the email that are frustrating. I know some JavaScript, but a little less knowledgable on PHP. So if necessary, I can code a bit.

I've tried looking through the E&P form settings but can't find anything that fixes the root problem of the emails getting sent to the customers will all of the information from the form rather than just the WooCommerce Cart. Any feedback is appreciated!